# What if any law is broken if Person B hugs Person A against A's expressed wishes?

Tags: united-states, self-defense

Here is a recent post about person A in the US who doesn't want to be hugged, yet keeps getting hugged despite voicing that the hugs are unwanted:

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9016

As described in the post, are those people committing a crime?  If so, what crime?  If not, what is the minimum that A would need to do to escalate the situation into a crime?

Answer (score 3):

This is the common law crime of [battery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(crime)) - “any unlawful and or unwanted touching of the person of another by the aggressor, or by a substance put in motion by him."

Many jurisdictions have abolished common law crimes and codified criminal behavior - it is a subset of what is commonly called “assault” and may be codified in that section.